# Owl Carousel scrolls to latest element when user is using macbook touchpad

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have a website where owl carousel is used to scroll through the cards.

http://example.develop-web.site/process/

When i'm using the mouse to scroll throught them, it scrolling the cards one by one. But if i try it on macbook with touchpad, it scrolls to lates item right away.

I've used this example to make this effect: 
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/mousewheel.html

It's using jquery.mousewheel.js

This is how the code looks for the layout:

```
                        <div class="vertical-slider owl-carousel" id="process-vertical-slider">

                            <?php while( have_rows('process_slider_items') ): the_row();

                                $image = get_sub_field('image');
                                $title = get_sub_field('title');
                                $description = get_sub_field('description');

                                ?>

                                <div class="item" data-count="<?php echo $count; ?>">
                                    <div class="process-slider-item">
                                        <div class="process-slider-item__image">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['image470x280']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <h3 class="process-slider-item__title"><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
                                        <p class="process-slider-item__description"><?php echo $description; ?></p>

                                        <div class="mask"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <?php $count++; endwhile; ?>

                        </div>
```

Here is the slider init

```
    /* Vertical Slider Process */
    $('#process-vertical-slider').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        loop: false,
        mouseDrag: true,
        touchDrag: false,
        pullDrag: false,
        rewind: false,
        autoplay: false,
        margin: 0,
        nav: false,
        smartSpeed: 1500,
        dots: true,
        dotsContainer: '#process-dots'
    });

    $('#process-dots .owl-dot').click(function () {
        $('#process-vertical-slider').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), 300]);
    });
```

I expect it to work with touchpad same as it does on mouse scroll.

Comment: Have you found the answer?